# How can I add a URL to my Google Calendar information without munging the fields?

Tags: json, google-api, google-calendar-api

I have a Google Calendar that I want to access via Google API in order to get a list of events as a JSON. With each event, I want to attach a URL for information about that event.

However, in the JSON data one gets back from the Google Calendar API, the "Description", which is a text field that one can fill out for every event in the Google Calendar web interface, is *not* included (as far as I can tall).

The one field in the Google Calendar web interface that I can enter a URL into that does get returned in the API's JSON is the "Where" field, which is intended for putting in some kind of description that can be located with Google Maps. And while this succeeds in getting the URL into the JSON, it means munging the purpose of the field. In other contexts, it will return an error as the URL will obviously not be found as a location on a Google Map.

Is there any way I can have a URL connected with individual events that I can pull via the API in a JSON without munging any fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the "Description" field does get returned if it is filled. My confusion stemmed from the fact that there is no empty "Description" key if "Description" is left empty in the Google Calendar interface.

So now I include a URL within the description, and then extract it from other text with some string parsing.

Answer (score 1):

If the "description" field is not returned you just need to add it in the update request.

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource
(read also about the "source" element)

Example (python):

```
event = <...>
event['description'] = url
service.events.update(calendarId=calendarId, eventId=eventId, body=event).execute()
```